# multilevel model vs multiple regression

Tags: multiple-regression, repeated-measures, multilevel-analysis

I have a situation where I wanted to use multiple regression to see how 3 predictor variables and predicted an outcome. However, I have two conditions in my experiment, which all participants undergo (a repeated measure). Therefore, I will use multilevel modelling as this allows me to have that repeated measure (whereas a typical linear multiple regression model does not).
So my questions are: 
1) where can I find information on how to do this? All the multilevel model stuff seems to be about analysing data in clusters (schools, classrooms etc) or about longitudinal analysis (time 1, time 2, time 3 etc). **Is it the longitudinal stuff I need to be looking at to understand how to do a multilevel model for my (non longitudinal) repeated measures experiment?**
2) will this give me a similar model to if I were doing a multiple regression - ie., **will I be able to understand the relative effects of each predictor** (including my experimental condition which is a repeated measure)

Comment: What measure is repeated?  How many repeats?

Comment: It is an experimental condition - there are two. Participants undergo both.